# Android check if device has notification access

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

So I am using the notifications access to know when certain apps are open and such, which works fine on Android O, but the problem I am having is that some devices apparently do not have access to this feature, so it displays this message.

`This feature is not available on this device`

Is there a way to know if the phone even has this feature available or not programmatically?

EDIT:
This is the code I currently use to send the user to the notification screen so they can enable access for my app, but as above, some devices like Moto E5 the phone itself does not allow this feature.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: You might consider using an [mvce] or something to explain in detail what "this feature" means and how exactly "it displays this message".